# Enable BLE pairing on request

Tags: bluetooth

I have a prototype using RedBear Lab's Blend micro platform (http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/). I am able to discover the BLE chip on my iPhone and connect / control the unit. However, the device is constantly advertising - how do I enable advertising only on user request.

For example, if I use my bluetooth headphone, it pairs only when I press a button to enable pairing. Can I do the same with this BLE chip?

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is not related to Arduino.

Comment: The RedBear Lab uses an Arduino @ Heart..

Comment: It uses an Atmel at heart, not an Arduino. However, your question relates to the BLE chip.